# How can I easily convert little endian pointers in hex dumps?

Tags: x64dbg

I am tracking down a data structure whose address is inside the second operand:

```
mov rcx, qword ptr ss:[rbp+E0]
```

When I look at the value of [rbp+E0] I see the following dump:

```
21 C4 FC 5E 00 00 00 00
```

This is the pointer to the data structure but it is stored as little endian. So I cannot simply copy the address. I have to transform it by hand into:

```
000000005EFCC421
```

Is there a common and easy way to handle these situations? I am currently using x64dbg as a debugger.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally there should be an option “display as dwords” or similar for the memory dump